# Priority-based queue sorted by deadline and constantly updated

Tags: anylogic

I want to sort packages created in my queue according to their deadline.
The call in the source for creating a deadline is:

```
agent.set_p_Deadline(f_getDeadlineID());
```

My variable Deadline is of type int and public.
My function f_getDeadlineID is of type int.

My agent priority in my queue calls a function.
This function is called f_getPriority();
I want this function to sort my deadlines from small to large and keep updating when new packets are added to the queue.

I have tried to define this function f_getPriority() in the function body, but I have not found any code that works. Attached is my example code that does not work. Can anyone help me to improve my code so that it works or suggest me another code?

[image: coding]

Comment: just setup the queue to use priority-based queuing and specify the agent deadline ID, no?

Comment: Hi, sorry to have to ask again. I have already set my queue to priority-based. When I enter agent.p_Deadline, I get an error message: cannot be resolved or is not a field . Also, nowhere does it specify that it will then be sorted by the smallest deadline. I must first specify that my smallest number of a deadline has the highest priority... or how would I do that?

Comment: best edit the original question or open a new one. These are the correct questions to ask :) (you will also find older questions with the same problem, search for "AnyLogic type casting" and "AnyLogic queue priority"